# How to use import & export in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have two files :

1. app.js
2. module.js

app.js will have expression,

```
import 'foo' from './module'
//use foo..
```

and module.js will have,

```
export default {expression}
```

But it is not working.
I'm currently using **Node 7.0.0**
I tries using **Webpack** with **babel-loader** and **es2015** preset but not working.

Comment: import syntax is not present in node.js yet, check this [thread](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import does not need the quotes, or braces if importing a *default* export:

```
import foo from './module';
```

Also your export should look something like:

```
export default expression;
```

and if the exported item is called *expression* you'd import it as:

```
import expression from './module';
```

(you need the braces when importing non-default exports).

Very good in-depth explanation here:

http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: bpinhosilva is correct; import won't work at all unless you are transpiling